# Проблема с функциями и циклами

Tags: python, функции, циклы, pygame

у меня возникла проблема. У меня есть 2 функции `ham` и `can`. Есть ли какая либо возможность заставить работать эти 2 функции параллельно в цикле `while`, если что это pyhton и я работаю с библиотекой pygame.

Comment: Читайте про распаралеливание процессов. Но запускать параллельные процессы в цикле - не очень хорошая (за редким исключением) идея.

Comment: я думаю надо так сделать: [ham, ham] [can, can]
ну думаю не поможет ну попробовать стоит.

Answer (score 0):

в цикле функции будут выполняться поочередно:

```
while True:
    ham()
    can()
```

после чего цикл будет повторяться, если только не ограничить это условием, скажем нуно 7мь повторений:

```
turn = 7
while turn > 0:
    ham()
    can()
    turn -= 1
```

если же необходимо выполнить одновременный запуск обеих функций, то можно использовать такой прием:

```
def a():
    print('foo')

def b():
    print('bar')

def both():
    a()
    b()

both()
```

где функция both при вызове запустит две другие